# listening to a model in component angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-changedetection

I'm using angular 2. I have a scenario where i have a component, interface and directive.

This directive is used to for autosuggestions and my interface is used as a model.

So whenever user selects a value, I am updating the model and is there a way where my component will listen to the model changes.

[directive - model - component interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWrPg.png)

how will the component listen to the model changes which I am making through directive? also Can a model be used to hold the data?

Comment: how will the component listen to the model changes which I am making through directive? also Can a model be used to hold the data?

Comment: You should update the question with the question, it will be better than saying it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inputs, outputs and binding like:

(not really an auto-complete but it should get you started)

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'auto-complete',
  template: `
  <select [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="valueChange.emit($event)">
    <option *ngFor="#val of values" [value]="val">{{val}}</option>
  </select>`})
export class AutoCompleteComponent {
  @Input() values:string[];
  @Output() valueChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  value:string;
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [AutoCompleteComponent],
  template: `
<auto-complete [value]="options" (valueChange)="onUpdate($event)"></auto-complete>
`})
export class AppComponent {
  options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  onUpdate(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way where i can listen to the emitted event not in template but in my component?

Comment: There might be a way but you shouldn't. `@Output()` should only be used to bind using `(outputName)="..."`. There might be other ways. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i created a directive for select2(used for auto-complete) a basic version just calling the select2 on the element. This directive is used across my application multiple times. I want to trigger an event whenever user selects anything. This event should be listened by the component. And there can be multiple components using this directive. So, Is there a way where I can have distinct event for every instance I used across the application?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can call the event handler with different parameters like `(valueChange)="onUpdate($event, 'autocompletion1')`. Is this what you're looking for?